# How do I get the complete list of the visitors IP address of a WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get the complete    list of the visitors IP address of a WordPress website in a CSV file?

Comment: You can usually find access logs at the server-level. For example on Apache it would have a certain format. You can download that and convert that to CSV format. If you want to do this at the php level, such a file will grow massive with each request unless you only store ips not already in there. For this you'd need to read first such as from a file or a database, etc. But generally `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives the machine's ip which made the request. (they could be behind a vpn, or you could be behind a load balancer etc). So you'd need to collect that and write.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This data isn't logged by WordPress by default. However, several WordPress plug-ins over the functionality. [This is a popular one.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tracemyip-visitor-analytics-ip-tracking-control/)

A web analytics platform may also capture the same data.